# Telegram bot on IIS: sendPhoto is not working

Tags: iis, telegram

```
function sendTelegramSMS($text,$tgimage) {


$botToken="tokenCODE";
$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
$chatId='1242433';  

//image
$params=[
    'chat_id'=>$chatId, 
    'text'=> $text,
    'photo'=> '@'.$tgimage,
];
$ch = curl_init($website . '/sendPhoto');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


//message
$params=[
    'chat_id'=>$chatId, 
    'text'=> $text,
];
$ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

}

$thefile= '/auth/prova.png';

sendTelegramSMS($reservation,$thefile);
```

This code works for sending messages (//message part), but doesn't work to send photos (//image part)...
i've tried a bounch of directory structure, nothing happen.
Hosted on Win10 with IIS.

Comment: When you sent photos, did it report any error message to explain why not work? How does the application get image? Does it read the image from any folder? If it gets image from folder, did you set application pool has full control permission to folder. Most likely application pool doesn't have permission to get image.

Comment: Resolved. it was a path error. I was considering the path root from wwwroot, but the root starts in c:\